# Замена цвета элемента SVG туда и обратно при клике

Tags: javascript, css, svg, анимация

Этот вопрос задавался много раз и есть хорошие решения при помощи использования `javascript`, например такой код:

```js
var shapeClick = document.getElementById("shape").addEventListener("click", changeColor);
var clicks = 0;
function changeColor(){
  if (shape.style.fill == "rgb(29, 172, 249)")
  {
    shape.style.fill = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
  }
  else {
    shape.style.fill = "rgb(29, 172, 249)";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>  
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
 width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" 
> 
         <circle id="shape" class="seat" cx="120" cy="125" r="50" style="fill: #1dacf9" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />>
 
   </svg> 
   </div>
```

Всё отлично работает, с помощью скриптов можно сделать очень много.

**Внимание вопрос**

Как сделать тоже самое на чистом `SVG (SMIL)`, не используя `javascript` и `CSS`.

Просто сменить цвет по клику не составляет труда:

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
 width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" 
> 
         <circle  cx="120" cy="125" r="50" style="fill: dodgerblue; stroke:black; stroke-width:2;" >
   <animate attributeName="fill" from="dodgerblue" to="red" fill="freeze" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.1s" calcMode="discrete"/>
    </circle>
  
   </svg>
```

Но как сменить цвет обратно, повторно кликая по объекту не приходит в голову.

Comment: Через скрытый checkbox?

Comment: Дело в том что что бы изменить цвет обратно нужно запомнить предъидущее состояние, то есть его где-то хранить. И вот с этим работает javascript. Либо хранить не предъидущее состояние но то что цвет был изменён. А как можно это сохранить без Javascript? Думаю никак.

Comment: _"Как сделать тоже самое на чистом SVG, SMIL не используя - javascript, CSS"_ - не понял, что именно не надо использовать. Я думал, что вопрос в том, как сделать без SMIL (он уже deprecated и для его работы надо подключать полифилы) и без скриптов одновременно. Или тире лишнее и надо использовать SMIL, но нельзя js и css? Если так, то в чём смысл затеи?

Comment: Да, именно так - без js и css, только SMIL.Мой пример выше именно использует SMIL, так что он пока поддерживается хромом. И отложили пока в гугле на неопределенное время deprecated SMIL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> if (shape.style.fill == "rgb(29, 172, 249)")
> ```

Так лучше не надо. А то кто-нибудь вернёт `1DACF9` вместо `rgb(29, 172, 249)` и всё.

> Как сделать тоже самое на чистом SVG, SMIL не используя - javascript, CSS

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

#red {
  display: none;
}

svg {
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
}

#shape {
  fill: green;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

#red:checked + svg #shape {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<label>  
  <input type=checkbox id=red>
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 250 250"> 
    <circle id="shape" class="seat" cx="120" cy="125" r="50" />
  </svg> 
</label>
```

> где и как обрабатывается клик по элементу?

В примере выше получился клик по всему `svg`.
Чтобы это исправить, можно воспользоваться `pointer-events`.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#red {
  display: none;
}

svg {
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
}

foreignObject svg {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#shape {
  fill: green;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#red:checked + svg #shape {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type=checkbox id=red>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 250 250">
    <circle id="shape" class="seat" cx="120" cy="125" r="50" />
  </svg>
</label>
```

Если внутри одного svg надо разместить несколько таких объектов, можно воспользоваться `foreignObject`, однако следует отметить, что его поддержка браузерами [весьма сомнительна](http://caniuse.com/#search=foreignobject).

```css
label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#red {
  display: none;
}

svg {
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
}

foreignObject svg {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#shape {
  fill: green;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#red:checked + svg #shape {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="125" fill="silver" />
  <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <label xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <input type=checkbox id=red>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 250 250">
        <circle id="shape" class="seat" cx="120" cy="125" r="50" />
      </svg>
    </label>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: как это работает ? не понятно? где и как обрабатывается клик по элементу?

Comment: @stack-it, упс.. клик по всему svg, не по кругу. Не уверен, что можно по кругу сделать...

Comment: @Qwertiy красиво, но всё же есть CSS в ответе.  Найти решение с поставленными условиями, было бы по настоящему круто.

Comment: @stack-it, дополнил ответ вариантом с кругом.

Comment: @Alexandr_T, дополнил ответ. Теперь кликабелен только круг и есть восзможность разместить несколько таких.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо я в курсе, что foreignObject может добавлять внутри файла SVG код HTML. Но задача была другая, только чистый SVG, SMIL

Answer (score 4):

Два варианта ответа, но каждый из них не полностью соответствует поставленной задаче. Привожу их, может быть примеры кому-то помогут найти  нужный ответ.

Вынужден давать их, так как торопят с закрытием вопроса. Решение где-то рядом. Прошу еще немного времени.

**Первый вариант**

```html
<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
 width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" 
> 
     <g  id="svg1">
        <rect  width="100%" height="100%" fill="white">   </rect>           
         <text  x="98" y="17" font-size="11" font-family="Ariel" text-anchor="middle" 
        fill="green" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.5px" >Click me</text>  
  </g> 
  <circle id="crc"  cx="120" cy="125" r="50" style="fill: dodgerblue; stroke:black; stroke-width:2;" >
   <animate id="an1" attributeName="fill" to="red" fill="freeze" begin="crc.click"   dur="0.01s" /> 
      <animate id="an2" attributeName="fill" to="dodgerblue" fill="freeze" begin="svg1.click"   dur="0.01s" /> 
   </circle> 
   </svg>
```

**Второй вариант**

```html
   <svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
 width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" 
> 
    <rect id="svg1" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white">   </rect>           
  <circle id="crc"  cx="120" cy="125" r="50" style="fill: dodgerblue; stroke:black; stroke-width:2;" >
  <animate id="an1" attributeName="fill" to="red" fill="freeze" begin="tored.click"   dur="0.01s" /> 
     <animate id="an2" attributeName="fill" to="dodgerblue" fill="freeze" begin="dodger.click"   dur="0.01s" /> 
 </circle> 
 <circle id="tored"  cx="100" cy="30" r="8" style="fill: red; stroke:black; stroke-width:1;" />
 <circle id="dodger"  cx="150" cy="30" r="8" style="fill: dodgerblue; stroke:black; stroke-width:1;" />
 
   </svg>
```